# Can I set a datafield value twice in a single mysql command

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Suppose there is a data field education in my table profile, now I want to update education='01' where earlier education was 'BA' , similarly education='02' where education was 'MD'

So I can do this task like this

```
update profile set education='01' where education='BA';
update profile set education='02' where education='MD';
```

My question is can I do this task in one command only like

```
   update profile set education='01' where education='BA' and set education='02' where education='MD';
```

This syntax is wrong, please tell me is this possible and how ?
If **it is not possible, than also please let me know about it...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in the `SET` clause, but be careful to include an `ELSE` case which sets the column to its current value --  otherwise, the rows that aren't matched by the two cases will be set to `NULL`.

```
UPDATE profile
SET education = 
  CASE
    WHEN education = 'BA' THEN '01'
    WHEN education = 'MD' THEN '02'
    /* MUST include an ELSE case to set to current value, 
       otherwise the non-matching will be NULLed! */
    ELSE education
  END
```

Comment: Or, more performant and concise, `UPDATE profile SET education = CASE education WHEN 'BA' THEN '01' WHEN 'MD' THEN '02' END WHERE education IN ('BA','MD')`: in this case `ELSE` is not required as one doesn't waste resource in "updating" columns that don't change.

Comment: If performance is the issue then I would stay with the two update statements from the question.  Still +1 as this is a correct answer to the stated question.